# Shared assemblies in one location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, shared-libraries

I have a big project with many subprojects.
(as mentioned in the drawing)

Both `WebSiteA` and `WebSiteB` has referenced to *both* DLL projects.

however when I change the dll's - I need to update *each* bin in each webSite.

I Don't want that.

*I know I can put them in `GAC` but I was told not to  (don't ask me why please.)*

[image]

Is there any solution like :

[image]

so when I update any dll - I put it only at one place ? (and so the dll's won't be at each site's `bin`)

Comment: Isn't it possible to extract the common features from both projects and create a common dll that will be eventually be referenced by WebSiteA and by WebSiteB? This way WebsiteA and WebsiteB updates will not collide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a trick with the `.refresh` file reference, *but not tested on the live server*.

First place your common dll, on a common directory.
Second on each bin, place the `*.refresh` file together with the dll, that says inside from where to update the dll if a new version is found.

and so you have inside the Bins something like:

```
mySuperModule.dll
mySuperModule.dll.refresh
```

and inside the **mySuperModule.dll.refresh** the location of the module that need to check for update ->

```
d:\Dlls\mySuperModule.dll
```

where `d:\dlls` are the common place for the dlls that search for new updates.

At the end you only update the common directory dlls, and you left the projects make the rest automatic.

Comment: Quite an interesting way around that, might try that.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough I have done that locally, and works. But on live server we make update one by one all the server - we have the same issue as you have :)

Comment: @Aristos So lets say I have a project myGame and i need to reference a dll. when I reference an outside dll - it is copied to the local bin.....so where is the benefit ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir In my project I build total 10 dll modules, all this libraries are copy to the bin automatically. But some of them, let say 4 of them they use one common dll to build, let say a DAL library. So I am update only one dll, and then on the build this 4 dlls automatic take all together the new version of the common dll, they build, and then copy 4+1 to the final bin automatically. If I have to copy the dal dll I must copy it with out error 5 times 4 on the modules, one on the final bin.

Comment: @Aristos can you goto chat ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19041/room-for-royi-namir-and-aristos

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the GAC is to provide that functionality, if you don't use that then you can't share the DLLs in the way you want. This is due to how sites are secured and separated from each other.